# Facebook Login Dialog Doesn't Close after Signup - Android Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm actually utilizing ParseFacebookUtils to login to the application. Everything works perfectly except for one minor nuisance. After logging in/signing up, the facebook login screen refreshes as a blank Facebook login. It isn't until you exit that it completes the signup/login. The code below is what is being utilized.

```
    public void showUserList() {
    if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()!=null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), newDashboard.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

      mBtnFb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(MainActivity.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                  if (user == null) {
                      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                  } else if (user.isNew()) {
                      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");


                  } else {
                      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                      showUserList();
                      getUserDetailsFromParse();

                  }
                  showUserList();
              }

          });

      }

  });
```

Comment: As a side note, onActivityResult isn't called until the refreshed login window is closed.